# Filling NaN values in a Pandas DataFrame conditionally on the values of non-NaN columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question regarding filling `NaN` values in a Pandas `DataFrame` conditionally on
the values of non-`NaN` columns. To illustrate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__

0.18.1

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   'b': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'x': [0.5, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0],
                   'y': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'z': [0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0, 0.4]})

df.ix[[2,4], ['x','y','z']] = np.nan

print df

   a  b  c    x    y    z
0  1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
1  0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
2  0  0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
4  1  0  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now suppose I have some default values, that depend on the first three columns:

```
default_c = pd.Series([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
default_a = pd.Series([0.2, 0.2, 0.2], index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

In other words, I'd like to paste in `default_c` for the `NaN` values in row 2, and paste in `default_a` in row 4. To do this, I came up with the following somewhat inelegant solution:

```
nan_x = np.isnan(df['x'])
is_c = df['c']==1
nan_c = nan_x & is_c

print nan_c

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

df.ix[nan_c, default_c.index] = default_c.values

print df

   a  b  c    x    y    z
0  1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
1  0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
2  0  0  1  0.5  0.5  0.5
3  0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
4  1  0  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a better way to do this using the `fillna()` function?

For example, the following doesn't work, I'm guessing because I am filling a slice of the `DataFrame`:

```
df.loc[df['a']==1].fillna(default_a, inplace=True)

print df

   a  b  c    x    y    z
0  1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
1  0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
2  0  0  1  0.5  0.5  0.5
3  0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
4  1  0  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But this long line does:

```
df.loc[df['a']==1] = df.loc[df['a']==1].fillna(default_a)

print df

   a  b  c    x    y    z
0  1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
1  0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
2  0  0  1  0.5  0.5  0.5
3  0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
4  1  0  0  0.2  0.2  0.2
```

Anyways, just looking for advice on how to make this code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set `a, b, c` columns as a multi-index and use pandas [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns).

First, you would need a frame of defaults. In your setting it can be:

```
df0 = pd.concat([default_a, default_c], axis=1).T
df0.index = pd.Index([(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)], names=list("abc"))
df0
Out[148]: 
         x    y    z
a b c               
1 0 0  0.2  0.2  0.2
0 0 1  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Then set a multi-index to df1, apply `combine_first`, and reset an index:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df1
Out[151]: 
         x    y    z
a b c               
1 0 0  0.5  0.0  0.1
0 1 0  0.2  0.0  0.1
  0 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
    1  0.2  1.0  0.0
1 0 0  NaN  NaN  NaN

df1.combine_first(df0)
Out[152]: 
         x    y    z
a b c               
0 0 1  0.5  0.5  0.5
    1  0.2  1.0  0.0
  1 0  0.2  0.0  0.1
1 0 0  0.5  0.0  0.1
    0  0.2  0.2  0.2

df1.combine_first(df0).reset_index()
Out[154]: 
   a  b  c    x    y    z
0  0  0  1  0.5  0.5  0.5
1  0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
2  0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
3  1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
4  1  0  0  0.2  0.2  0.2
```

A side effect is a different sort order of the output. To keep the order, we may use the original index (if it's monotonic and unique, otherwise use an additional temp column instead):

```
df2 = df.reset_index().set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df2
Out[156]: 
       index    x    y    z
a b c                      
1 0 0      0  0.5  0.0  0.1
0 1 0      1  0.2  0.0  0.1
  0 1      2  NaN  NaN  NaN
    1      3  0.2  1.0  0.0
1 0 0      4  NaN  NaN  NaN

df2.combine_first(df0).reset_index().set_index('index').sort_index()
Out[160]: 
       a  b  c    x    y    z
index                        
0      1  0  0  0.5  0.0  0.1
1      0  1  0  0.2  0.0  0.1
2      0  0  1  0.5  0.5  0.5
3      0  0  1  0.2  1.0  0.0
4      1  0  0  0.2  0.2  0.2
```

Comment: Nice! Eliminates the need to loop over columns in my solution.